# Running mutiple instance of an app

Tags: javascript, node.js, spawn

Below is my code where I am trying to get different user id's. For each id I am maintaining the database. How can the spawn the same process for different user. Only process (including DB and app) will be used by one user.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.get('/user/:id', function(req, res) {
  res.send('user' + req.params.id);    
});
app.listen(3000);
```

By doing this example, my motive is to learn run multiple instance of this server. I searched in google and found that it is possible through spawn. Any help on how can I spawn a process.

Comment: that seems counter intuitive to how nodejs works.

Comment: @Tushar Yes I can do that but how to run based on the user id request. Example, if 2 user id request comes, I need to spawn only two servers. This is just an approach, not sure its possible or not

Answer (score 0):

You could check node clusters.
Create a new worker for every user id https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html
All share the same server port.